# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scipy._lib._ccallback' when import scipy onto Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python-3.x, scipy, jupyter-notebook

I have this error when I am trying to import scipy, seaborn and sklearn onto my Jupyter Notebook even though I have re-installed scipy multiple times on my Anaconda Prompt. What should I do? Thank you!:

````
<ipython-input-37-4363d2be0702> in <module>
----> 1 import scipy

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\__init__.py in <module>
    117     del _NumpyVersion
    118 
--> 119     from scipy._lib._ccallback import LowLevelCallable
    120 
    121     from scipy._lib._testutils import PytestTester

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scipy._lib._ccallback'```
````